# 14.04 how to connect/mount galaxy s4

Tags: 14.04

How can I connect to my Galaxy S4 via usb?  When I connect it via usb all I get are errors saying unable to mount device.

Comment: I also get error messages, whether I try to mount using MTP or PTP.

Comment: I don't even get an error, just, nothing happens. However, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055304/unable-to-mount-samsung-android-in-ubuntu

Comment: Did you do a <b>clean</b> update to <i>14.04?</i> If yes then there might be some problem with your memory card because i don't think that <b>Ubuntu</b> runs/supports Samsung driver software's so actually the error is with mounting the memory card. This answer might not help you much but i think it maybe useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a guy who created an app for it. Looks like it works with older
versions of Ubuntu 13.04, 12.10 and 12.04 for example. Maybe it will work
since 14.04 is closely based on the same architecture as 13.04. Try it out:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-mount-android-40-ubuntu-go-mtpfs.html

I'm considering getting A Galaxy S4 soon. If I have success I'll post it.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug... Same message occurs when I plug any android device into one of my usb ports... even though it says "unable to mount" the device actually does mount... From your phone, you also have to enable/choose mtpfs (MTP)

Find out how to enable MTP on your respective device... this should fix the problem...

PS. When you connect... Give it some time to register... It may take up to 10-15 seconds for Ubuntu to recognize your device...